# How to send private messages?

Tags: support, moderators, private-messages

How do I send private messages to another user on the website? More specifically, how can I send private messages to a moderator on the website?

Comment: A relevant response to your first more general question can be found [in this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/how-to-contact-a-specific-user-is-there-any-sort-of-pm-private-message-fa). Regarding your more specific second question, I have seen people successfully get the attention of a moderator through tactful effort in the main chat room, but that is certainly not private.

Comment: To expand on J.W.Perry's suggestion, now there exists also a chatroom created specifically for issues needing moderator's attention, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19316). It is called [Math Mods' Office](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/20352/math-mods-office).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to contact a *specific* moderator: check their [profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). Some moderators provide their email address in the profile, and indicate it may be used for moderation-related inquiries. If they don't, then this is not an option.

If you want to contact *some* moderator, you can use a free-form flag on any relevant post (or, if no such post exists, on your own post). An alternative is the [moderators chatroom for maths.SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office).

---

SE [does not provide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431) any private messaging system for contacting  non-moderators.